# show hide on logic js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I have some logic

```
$("#finish-button").click(function () {
    $(".hidebuttonvresults").hide();
    $(".showbuttonvresults").show();
});
```

This works for most of my pages, however one page does not have `#finish-button`. The only unique is id is `#question-number` but I only want this action to happen when the ID prints Question 15 of 15.

Any idea how to alter my logic to include this extra factor? I was trying

```
 var str = $('#question-number').html();
    if (str.indexOf("Question 40 of 46") !== -1) {
        $(".hidebuttonvresults").hide();
        $(".showbuttonvresults").show();
    }
```

but it does not work

Comment: what is `str` in your example?  And what does it mean "when the ID prints Question 15 of 15"?  Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Something like: `$('[#=*]:contains("Question 15 of 15")').click(...)`?

Comment: thanks ill try this logic

Comment: @andi question updated

Comment: Whoops I just noticed that last selector isn't valid, try `$('[id]:contains("Question 15 of 15")')`. Meaning get any element with an `id` and contains the text `"Question 15 of 15"`.

Comment: is there a separate JS function that updates the content of `#question-number`?

Comment: @andi no that is the function

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thaks, im still trying it out

Comment: oh, I thought it was dynamically updated... never mind.  So your original code should work.  You're running it on DOM ready, right?  not before?

Comment: @andi yes it is dynamic, as in the number starts 1

Comment: @BenjaminOats I think you need to create a fiddle to demonstrate the exact problem.